# Does Files.lines read all lines into memory?

Tags: java, file

In the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) it says

> Read all lines from a file as a `Stream`.

Does that necessary mean that it's loading the entire file? For example:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("myfilename.txt"))) {
        stream.forEach(x -> {
```

if `myfilename` is *100GB* , will `Files.lines` load the entire *100GB*?

Comment: The question itself is good, but it lacks research effort. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) of the method clearly explains that the method populates **lazily**. So if you would `limit` the stream, let's say to `100` elements, it will only read `100` lines. To be fair, you need to follow the method to the more general version to find that note.

Answer (score 9):

Well, the link you provided states it already:

> Unlike readAllLines, this method does not read all lines into a List, but instead populates lazily as the stream is consumed.

So for every time your `for-each` block is called, a new line is read.

Answer (score 6):

No, it doesn't load the entire file into memory. It internally uses a `BufferedReader` with the default buffer size, repeatedly calling `readLine()`.

Answer (score 2):

A new method lines() has been added since 1.8, it lets BufferedReader returns content as Stream.this method does not read all lines into a List, but instead populates lazily as the stream is consumed.when you call for-each,then a new line is reload. hope can help you!

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the Spliterator if Files.lines is used with a parallel stream. Than all processed lines will be stored in the Spliterator which makes it unuseable for large files.